# Iptables default chains priority?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, rpyc

In order to check the RPyC module, I created 2 VM's (Ubuntu and Xubuntu), and tried to communicate between them.
At first, I ran the RPyC server on the **ubuntu VM**, and connected from the **Xubuntu VM**. Went well!

Then, I switched between them. I ran the server on the **Xubuntu VM** this time, and tried to connect from the **Ubuntu VM**. 
I've got a "No route to host" message.

The first thing I though is to try the firewall.
When i shut down the firewall, I managed to connect, so I tried to look at the Iptables rules-list in the machine.

The INPUT chain in the iptables had bunch of different rules, where all of them, except from one was **ACCEPT**, when the first one was **ACCEPT all**.
The last one was **REJECT all** (don't ask why, it wasn't my configuration).

I tried to delete the rules one by one until I was able to connect, and when I deleted the last one, the **REJECT all**, I was able to connect.

My question is- why, although it was the last rule in the chain list, the REJECT all overrides the ACCEPT all rule? is there any prioritise of the default Iptables CHAINS?

Thanks in advance,

Idan

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, rules are read from top to bottom.
Could you try to explicitly append the rules you want at the top?
For example for ssh:

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT